# to check if sum of all numbers in list is odd or even with the help of xor

Tags: number-theory, logic

We need to check if the sum of elements in the array or say a list is odd or even , how does xoring( applying xor operation) all elements of array help ? Can anyone prove as why xor of all numbers gives us correct answer ? Examples will be greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

If true is 1 and false is 0, then recall  1 xor 0 = 1 and 0 xor 0 = 1 xor 1 = 0. So if you take two consecutive elements in a list and xor their reductions modulo 2, you see that odd xor odd = even xor even = even and only odd xor even = odd. So xoring things gives you the same result (in terms of even or odd) as adding them then looking.